# Strength 1 in Original Fallout 1

Tags: fallout

I've never been a strong character in Fallout 3, as it was a pretty boring skill to have ('woo I  can carry more junk'). I also think luck is boring too, and I think I've made the huge mistake of making my character in Fallout 1 have 1 strength and 1 luck.

The mechanics are utterly different! Utterly! I am utterly useless in combat (I'm using a knife):

```
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
You are not strong enough to use this weapon properly
You missed
Cav Rat was hit for 8 hit points and was killed
```

It's ridiculous. I've put about 4 hours into this game, wandering around junktown and such and I really don't want to have to create a new character. What are my options? Anyway to increase strength and luck?

Or is there some sort of skill my character can still take advantage of? I'm praying energy weapons or explosives?

```
Strength: 01
Perception: 04
Endourance: 08
Charisma: 06
Intelligence: 10
Agility: 10
Luck: 1
```

Help my character find his calling!

Comment: There is no strength requirement for speech. IIRC, you can play through the entire game using speech and stealth while not wielding weapons.

Comment: Although true, you will not want to be doing this on your first playthrough.  A talking-run means you need to know exactly where to go and what to do because you can't survive wandering around.

Comment: You can probably use a trainer and adjust your endurance and Charisma down for more strength.  4 strength is enough due to the power armor rising it at later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure your character will ever really be good at combat with those stats. Your agility is good for ranged skills, but you're too weak to use guns properly. As mentioned, you could go full sneak and speech and try and do the game without combat as much as possible.

There are a couple of ways to increase your strength and luck.

Ways to increase Strength:

- T-51b power armor increases Strength by 3.
- The Brotherhood of Steel can perform an operation to increase Strength by 1, assuming the player can afford it.
- Buffout temporarily increases Strength by 2.
- Several perks increase Strength. Adrenaline Rush raises Strength by 1 when the player has less than 50% health. Gain perk can be used to boost Strength by 1. Some Perks raise Strength when checking for modifiers. Heave Ho! raises Strength by 2 for purposes of throwing weapons. Weapon Handling raises Strength by 3 for purposes of checking the minimum Strength needed to use a weapon.
- The Bruiser trait raises Strength by 2, but lowers the player's AP.

(http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Strength)

Ways to increase Luck

- Chuck in the Boneyard - Adytum can increase your Luck permanently by one point via the mysteries of the Tarot.

(http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Luck)